# SSL session tickets

Tags: http, ssl, web, request

Why one has to use tickets to avoid multiple SSL handshakes. Is it impossible to use HTTP persistent (keep alive) connection and send multiple GET... requests in a single SSL session? There is timeout in Apache for exmaple, but it can be reconfigured (in my case the web server is not random but fixed and have full control).

Answer (score 0):

SSL sessions are not multiple requests inside a single TCP session like HTTP keep-alive, but multiple TCP connections inside a single SSL session. The purpose is to reduce the time it takes to establish the SSL connection, that is make a reduced handshake with SSL resumption instead of a full handshake.

Of course you can combine both technologies, that is create a TCP connection, upgrade it to SSL and then send multiple HTTP requests. Later, after the TCP connection is long already closed (takes resources at the server) you do another TCP connection and resume the SSL session from before and do another bunch of HTTP requests inside.